# How to Add Html in PHP

Tags: php, html

How I can echo the whole code below.. The problem is another echo inside of the button..

Thanks!

```
<button type="submit" id="addres" name="addres" <?php echo $addres_disabled;?> class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Send Addres</button>
```

Comment: Do you want the `<?php echo` to be displayed?

Comment: If there is a <?php, close it, then insert your line of code above, then reopen. If you're outside a <?php ?> pair, just insert this line directly.

Comment: now u have some best solution, try it, and choose the best answer and mark as accpeted, this will help to others

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '<button type="submit" id="addres" name="addres" '.$addres_disabled.' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Send Addres</button>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is way too small question. A bit google search would have helped you.

```
echo '<button type="submit" id="addres" name="addres" '.$addres_disabled.' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Send Addres</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
<?php
$addres_disabled = 'disabled';
echo '<button type="submit" id="addres" name="addres" '.$addres_disabled.' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Send Addres</button>';
?>
```

You can use it outside the `<?php?>` as you are already using, something like:

```
<?php
/*** Your php code ***/
$addres_disabled = 'disabled';
/*** Your php code ***/
?>

<button type="submit" id="addres" name="addres" <?=$addres_disabled?> class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Send Addres</button>';

<?php
/*** Your rest php code ***/
?>
```

Close PHP tag, before starting your HTML, and after HTML, you can continue the PHP tags, **depends on your rest code**.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can juste do :

```
<?php echo '<button type="submit" id="addres" name="addres" '.  $addres_disabled .' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Send Addres</button>' ?>
```